# Accessing outside the dimensions in array created by a double pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Is this the correct method to define an 5*3 matrix using double pointers?`

```
 int **M1;
 M1 = (int **)malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));
 for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    M1[i] = (int *)malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
 }`
```

If so, how can I assign `M1[3][15] = 9` in the code and still get no error? And why am I getting a segmentation error in assigning `M1[6][3]=2`?

I understood after few such initializations that I created a `5*xx` array, i.e. I couldn't go above 5th row but I could assign any value to the number of columns. How should I create just a 5*3 array?

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: If you go out of bounds you will have *undefined behavior*. The C language has no bounds checking, it allows you to [shoot yourself in the foots](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot) as much as you like. Just don't do it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I was able to go out of bounds by extending rows not columns. I was confused as to how did it happen. I don't intend to go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're allocating memory for 5 pointers

```
M1 = (int **)malloc(5 * sizeof(int *));
```

and later, you're trying to access beyond that, based on an unrelated value of `m`

```
for (i=0;i<m;i++)
```

when `m` goes beyond `4`, you're essentially accessing out of bound memory.

A better way to allocate will be

```
int m = 5;
M1 = malloc(m * sizeof(*M1));
if (M1) 
{
 for (i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    M1[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(*M1[i]));
 }
}
```

> *couldn't go above 5th row but I could assign any value to the number of columns*.

NO, you *can not*. In *any* way possible, accessing out of bound memory invokes  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: sorry, I forgot to edit m to 5. Please recheck the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since Sourav tackled the UB case, I'll answer

> How should I create just a 5*3 array?

Why not rely on automatic variables? Unless you've a compelling reason not to, use them

```
int matrix[5][3];
```

If you don't know the dimensions in advance, and don't prefer doing the double pointer manipulation, flatten it like this:

```
int *m = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);
// accessing anything from 0 to (rows * cols) - 1 is permitted

// helper to make usage easier
int get_element(int *m, int i, int j, int cols) {
    return m[i * cols + j];
}
```

OTOH, if you only don't know the first dimension at compile-time, then you may do:

```
typedef int (Int5) [5];   // cols known at complie-time
int rows = 3;
Int5 *r = malloc(rows * sizeof(Int5));
r[0][0] = 1;   // OK
r[0][5] = 2;   // warning: out of bounds access
```

With this method you get a bit more type safety due to the compiler knowing the size in advice.